# PYTHON 2.7: intern() an Unicode Object

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

it seems to be not possible to intern() an unicode object in python 2.7.  See Error below:

```
 In [70]: intern(u"Char")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-27fe3029e1ea> in <module>()
----> 1 intern(u"Char")

TypeError: intern() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

Is there other packages for python 2.7 which could intern an unicode object?

Thx in advance=)

Comment: Why do you need this? FWIW, `intern` is no longer accessible in Python 3. But in Python 2 you _could_ do `intern(u"Char".encode('utf8'))`

Comment: 1. why **intern** will be not more accessible in python3?
2. right, but if i want to make a look-up, than i need also encode anytime the string which I want to looks-up. so, than it is not so performant -(

Comment: **1** Sorry, I made a mistake. In Python 3, `intern` has been moved to `sys.intern`. My excuse is that I never use it, I let Python handle interning for me. ;) **2** Agreed, it's a performance hit, and messy, to have to encode your Unicode strings that you want to use as dictionary keys. OTOH, have you noticed a significant speed improvement by using `intern` on plain strings?

Comment: no prob=) yeah, it was around 50% of speed improvements. Because my keys are emojis and the size of emojis are minimum 4KB. So a pretty big difference=)